# How to check if Element Is Visible with an element that is hidden using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Can someone please offer any suggestion on how to handle this?

From the HTML:-

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var RequiredFieldValidator1 = document.all ? document.all["RequiredFieldValidator1"] : document.getElementById("RequiredFieldValidator1");
RequiredFieldValidator1.controltovalidate = "ddlAlligator";
RequiredFieldValidator1.focusOnError = "t";
RequiredFieldValidator1.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
RequiredFieldValidator1.initialvalue = "";
var ValidationSummary1 = document.all ? document.all["ValidationSummary1"] : document.getElementById("ValidationSummary1");
ValidationSummary1.headertext = "The form is missing required information.  Please review your answers.";
//]]>
</script>
```

My C# Code:

```
private By NoFieldHeader = By.XPath("//label/div[text()='The form is missing required']");

    public bool IsNoField()
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.00));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(NoFieldHeader ));
        return true;
    }
```

Error:-

> An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException' occurred in WebDriver.Support.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Timed out after 3 seconds

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your XPath is `text()=...`. That means that the provided string is the entirety of the message when from the posted HTML it is not. You need to either use `contains()` or change `text()=...` to be the full string, `"The form is missing required information.  Please review your answers."`

If there are times when that element will not be present, you will need to add a `try-catch`, catch the `WebDriverTimeoutException`, and return `false` in that case.

Comment: Thanks! You are correct. That solved my problem. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as you wrote it. You told it wait for three seconds until the element in question loaded and if nothing timeout. Either increase your wait time to accommodate the element, or [try another condition](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions).